# Multiple intervals and functions on the same element in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to set and clear different intervals for different function to control the same element
but something does not work properly:

```
var i = 0;
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

function minus(){
    i--;
    myDiv.innerHTML = i;
}
function plus(){
    i++;
    myDiv.innerHTML = i;
}

var check = "xxx";

$('#buttonMinus').click(function() {
    if(check !== "MM"){
        clearInterval(plus);
        check = "MM";
    }
    MINUS = setInterval(minus, 500);
});

$('#buttonPlus').click(function() {
    if(check !== "PP"){
        clearInterval(minus);
        check = "PP";
    }
    PLUS = setInterval(plus, 500);
});
```

What I'm doing wrong?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4dh5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ypu should send the result from setInterval into clearInterval, but you're not - you're sending the function.

instead of:

```
clearInterval(plus);
```

do:

```
clearInterval(PLUS);
```

and the same for minus/MINUS.

You'll also need to check if you have a value in those variables first. Something like this:

```
var check = "xxx";
var PLUS = null;
var MINUS = null;

$('#buttonMinus').click(function() {
    if(check !== "MM"){
        if (PLUS) {
            clearInterval(PLUS);
        }
        check = "MM";
    }
    MINUS = setInterval(minus, 500);
});

$('#buttonPlus').click(function() {
    if(check !== "PP"){
        if (MINUS) {
            clearInterval(MINUS);
        }
        check = "PP";
    }
    PLUS = setInterval(plus, 500);
});
```

Comment: I replaced them but it shows the errors: MINUS is not defined, PLUS is not defined...

Comment: It works! However do you think that is useful my "strategy" of `check`, `MM` and `PP` to define and update the state of intervals?

Comment: I think it's fine for two - if there were more I'd probably move to having a single interval going, calling a function that checks the state. But that's really an entirely different question.

Comment: there's one problem: if I click more than one time on the buttons the clearInterval does not work! [Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4dh5/1/) please help

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:
buttons now set the Interval only if **PLUS** or **MINUS** are `null` (no problem if repetitive clicking)
and then reset the opposite **PLUS** or **MINUS** to `null`:

```
var i = 0;
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

function minus(){
    i--;
    myDiv.innerHTML = i;
}
function plus(){
    i++;
    myDiv.innerHTML = i;
}

var PLUS = null;
var MINUS = null;

$('#buttonMinus').click(function() {
    if (PLUS) {
        clearInterval(PLUS);
        PLUS = null;
    }
    if(MINUS == null){
        MINUS = setInterval(minus, 500);
    }
});

$('#buttonPlus').click(function() {
    if (MINUS) {
        clearInterval(MINUS);
        MINUS = null;
    }
    if(PLUS == null){
        PLUS = setInterval(plus, 500);
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4dh5/2/)**

Many thanks to Chris Tavares for Help! :)